# Swift_TransportException while sending email

Tags: yii2, zoho

I am trying to send reset password email from my project to user and used zohomail for as the mail server.

my project is based on yii 2 framework

But i am getting error as :
connection could not be established with host smtp.zoho.com [Connection refused #111]

my configuration:

```
'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.zoho.com',
            'username' => 'info@mycompany.com.np',
            'password' => '**********',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

To connect to an host with SSL/TLS you must have OpenSSL installed and openssl module enabled in PHP. You should check if you have it and is enabled with phpinfo().